# concatenate 2 object that get from axios request in vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vuejs3

there are users data that get  by
location ids. the locations data  look like this

```
locations = ([
         { "name" : "St Skid row" , "id" : 1},
         { "name" : "St Manhatan" , "id" : 2},
         { "name" : "St Golf" , "id" : 3}
      ])
```

lets say the users data in databases look like this

```
users = [
{"name" : "rikardo", "locationId" : 1},
{"name" : "valention", "locationId" : 1},
{"name" : "marcello", "locationId" : 2},
{"name" : "Ronaldo", "locationId" : 2},
{"name" : "Adriano", "locationId" : 3},
]
```

then get user by locations id

```
userBylocationIds.value = await axios.post(`${API_ORIGIN}/auth/v1/user/location`,locationIds
```

return data look like this

```
dataUsersByLocationId = [
   {"name" : "rikardo" },
   {"name" : "valention" },
   {"name" : "marcello" },
   {"name" : "Ronaldo" },
   {"name" : "Adriano" },
]
```

i want to combine both object, but i cant because dataUsersByLocationId did'n contain location id

expected after join

```
expected = [
   {"name" : "rikardo" ,"location": "St Skid row"}
   {"name" : "valention" ,"location": "St Skid row"}
   {"name" : "marcello" ,"location": "St Manhatan"} 
   and so on
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.reduce on users array and get a combine array of user and location

```
const combineArray = users.reduce((pre, cur) => {
    const userLocation = locations.filter(loc => loc.id === cur.locationId)[0];
    pre.push({name: cur.name, location: userLocation.name});
    return pre;
}, []);
```

return value:

```
[
        {
            "name": "rikardo",
            "location": "St Skid row"
        },
        {
            "name": "valention",
            "location": "St Skid row"
        },
        {
            "name": "marcello",
            "location": "St Manhatan"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ronaldo",
            "location": "St Manhatan"
        },
        {
            "name": "Adriano",
            "location": "St Golf"
        }
    ]
```